# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

for no reason in getting this error on

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: On which page above error show to you?

Comment: main home page and every page im getting this error

Comment: Is There any solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need try to change the database hostname 
from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` into the following file.

> app\etc\local.xml

Comment: Have you check your host entry into the given file?

Answer (score 0):

This is showing that your MySQL client can't connect to the MySQL server.

I'm going to assume you're using `localhost` as the host in your `app/etc/local.xml` config so it'll be attempting to look for the MySQL socket at (usually) `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` on the server. If it can't find it, then it throws this error. Check that MySQL is running and that this file (or another similar) exists.

If it is running but it just isn't connecting still, then try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` to have the client attempt to connect via TCP instead of a via the `.sock` file.

If you're running on an environment where the MySQL server isn't located either via the `.sock` file or at IP address `127.0.0.1`, then use the correct IP address/Hostname instead. For example, some hosts may put the DB on a hostname like `db1.myhost.com` so your host entry in your config would look as `<host>db1.myhost.com</host>`

Comment: No i am not running this site on local buddy it is up on server

Comment: I understand that, when I say `localhost` I mean the value in your `app/etc/local.xml` file, and by your system I mean the server that the site is on.